# VS Code does not confirm pulls/pushes, does not show results

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code Editor, when I do Pull/Push, it does it silently with no confirmation. I need to see what changes have occurred as a result of my Pull, for example (similar to how Eclipse shows a box with what changes the Pull has brought in). Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: What for? I mean what use is it to see what changes were made compared to your local state? That sounds more like an issue regarding the use of branches to me. And it only pulls silently when there's no difference which would result in a conflict.

Comment: What do you mean "What for?" To see the commits that have occurred in the interim that have been missed and are now getting pulled in. Eclipse shows you what it's bringing in compared to your last pull.

Comment: Hm, I still find I a bit weird that you actually do this - but I won't ask for the reasons any further. I guess [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1252509/how-to-see-diff-of-each-commit-with-visual-studio-code) might be what you were looking for ;)

Comment: just perform a compare between 2 commits